# Postman null value in optional string field

Tags: postman

I'm writing a POST request in Postman. There is an optional field, which can contain `null` or a date (a string value). So, I have this in my POST request body:

```
"paidOn": "{{date}}"
```

It works great with non-null values, obviously. But if I put `null` in the `paidOn` column, it ends up like a string `"null"`. If I put nothing, it ends up like an empty string `""`. In both cases, I get a 400 error.

I tried another approach too:

```
"paidOn": {{date}}
```

This one works ok with empty fields, but doesn't when I have an actual date in it (like, `2020-04-13T14:39:52`) -> I get a 400 error.

Does anyone know how I could work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found something in another forum, which gave me an idea: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/42484/25137

I kept the following format:

```
"paidOn": {{date}}
```

And in the CSV file:

```
paidOn
"""non-null-value"""
null
```

Works like a charm.